# Android - Map overlay onTouchEvent / onTap howto?

Tags: android

I've implemented a Class that extends Overlay and also override the onTap / onTouchEvent (tried both).

Right now it seems like that event is triggered when you tap on the map regardless of position.
How can I make sure that the event is triggered only when you tap over the overlay you have added?

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The overlay covers the entire map.

If you only want tap events when they tap on one of your items in an `ItemizedOverlay`, use `onTap()`.

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare, can you elaborate what you mean? I tried onTap as well and the onTap still gets triggered when I tap anywhere on the map. Thanks, Tee

Comment: I have done a lot of development with `MapView` and `ItemizedOverlay`, and `onTap()` does *not* get called when you tap anywhere, only when you tap on an overlay item. Take a look at this project for an example: http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Maps/NooYawk/

Comment: Thanks! For me - all I needed this kind of simple example!

Comment: how do you detect that the screen was touched but none of them were tapped?

Comment: oh i see how you did it in your example, you would think there would be an idiot proof way.