# Android Overlay setting Boundary for ontap method?

Tags: android, android-mapview

Recently I have drew a custom polygon around my country by creating a overlay class and drew it using path. 
I have many sector of a map, each sector is divided and filled with color with a overlay class. However when I use the ontap function, only the last overlay item ontap function get called.

I believe is because I did not set a boundary for the overlay? The following is my overlay code

```
public class SectorOverlay  extends  Overlay{

CustomPolygon customPolygon =null;
Context context;

public SectorOverlay(Context context, CustomPolygon customPolygon) {
    this.context=context;
    this.customPolygon =customPolygon;
}
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) 
{
    shadow=false;

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
    paint.setColor(0x10000000);     
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    Point point1_draw = new Point();        

    if(customPolygon!=null)
    {

            Path path = new Path();
            path.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);
            for(int n=0;n<customPolygon.getCorrdinateList().size();n++)
            {

                GeoPoint sector1 = new GeoPoint((int)(customPolygon.getCorrdinateList().get(n).getLatitude()*1e6), (int)((customPolygon.getCorrdinateList().get(n).getLongitude())*1e6));
                if(n==0){
                    mapView.getProjection().toPixels(sector1, point1_draw);
                    path.moveTo(point1_draw.x,point1_draw.y);
                }else
                {
                    mapView.getProjection().toPixels(sector1, point1_draw);
                    path.lineTo(point1_draw.x,point1_draw.y);
                }
            }

            path.close();
            canvas.drawPath(path, paint);



    }

}
@Override
public boolean onTap(GeoPoint p, MapView mapView) {


    new CommonOpearation().showToast(context, customPolygon.getName());


return  true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It is being called for the "last" `Overlay`, because it is the topmost.** `MapView` draws its overlays from `0..end`, but when there is an event, the last drawn is on top, so it gets the event first, and **since you `return true` in `Overlay.onTap`** (same applies to `Overlay.onTouchEvent`, and practically a lot of Android events) **you're saying that the event is handled, therefore it doesn't bother calling the overlays down the line.** So the event handlers are called in `end..0` order.

I did not use `onTap`, but according to *CommonsWare* at [Android - Map overlay onTouchEvent / onTap howto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610008/android-map-overlay-ontouchevent-ontap-howto) if you use `ItemizedOverlay` you should get `onTap` only for your bounded/drawn area.
It is surely possible that common `onTap` and `onTouchEvents` are called for any touch point on screen. In this case you can find the `GeoPoint` with `getProjection` from `MapView` applying it reversly to (x,y) getting (lon,lat). Or using `onTap` (again, I haven't heard about this before).

If you need to do a hit-test with the drawn polygon of the overlay, here's one which helps zou determine whether the point is in the (not necessarily convex) polygon:
http://verkkoopetus.cs.utu.fi/vhanke/trakla/PointInPolygon.html

- for 2. `LStart.x = minXOfPolygon, LEnd.x = maxXOfPolygon, LStart.y = LEnd.y = 0`
  (you may need extend the line by 1 unit at `LStart.x` and `LEnd.x` just to be safe.)
- for 4. use `findIntersection` from http://workshop.evolutionzone.com/2007/09/10/code-2d-line-intersection/