# Android Overlay onTap() - determine whether it was this overlay specifically that was tapped

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android - Map overlay onTouchEvent / onTap howto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610008/android-map-overlay-ontouchevent-ontap-howto)

I have an Android application that makes use of a `MapView` with an `Overlay` (a blue pin) showing the location of a building chosen from a list of buildings.  When the user taps the overlay, I want to display a toast message showing the name and number of the building.  The problem I'm having is that my handling of `onTap()` in the overlay picks up *all* tap events, regardless of whether they tap on the blue pin or somewhere completely different on the map.

My code looks like this:

```
searchedPlaceOverlay = new SearchedPlaceOverlay(SearchPlaces.chosenPlace.getLocation(), this) {
    public boolean onTap(GeoPoint p, MapView mapView) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "<building name and #>", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
        return true;
    }
};
mv.getOverlays().add(searchedPlaceOverlay);
```

`SearchedPlaceOverlay` extends `com.google.android.maps.Overlay` and the blue pin displays fine on the map, it's just the non-discriminatory nature of `onTap()` being called that's causing issues.  Is there a simple way to determine whether it was this overlay specifically that was tapped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @tabbykitten said ItemizedOverlay would be simpler, but if you must not use it, you can use the the following approach:

1. Get coordinates X,Y from your marker
2. Get bounds from your markwe drawable. Depender on marker type, it may not be centered in geopoint.
3. Adjust bounds to position on geopoint.
4. Get x,y coordinates ot point tapped.
5. Check if it's inside adjusted marker bounds.

example code below:

```
public boolean onTap(GeoPoint p, MapView mapView) { 
  Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
  projection.toPixels(yourMarkerGeopoint, pointTap);
  yourMarker.copyBounds(boundsTap);
  boundsTap.offset(pointTap.x, pointTap.y);
  projection.toPixels(geoPoint, pointTap);
  if(boundsTap.contains(pointTap.x, pointTap.y)){
    //you tap on the marker
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are ItemizedOverlay with onTap(int index). Put your' overlays inside it. Then you know index which was tapped.

Comment: I may resort to this if need be, but ideally I'd like to avoid the additional code an ItemizedOverlay brings with it.

Comment: I am sorry but ItemizedOverlay is what you need. Read desription https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/ItemizedOverlay